# SSRS IF Statement with incorrect syntax

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, syntax, expression

I'm new to SSRS and find the syntax very difficult as well as the awful expression text box that makes it very hard to see where i've made errors.

I want to do IFF (First(Fields!TaxNumber.Value, "InvoiceHeader") = null, then only print IS02Chars.value, else print both IS02Chars and TaxNumber.Value.

```
  =IFF (First(Fields!TaxNumber.Value, "InvoiceHeader") = null ,
  ": " & First(Fields!ISO2Chars.Value, "InvoiceHeader"), 
  ": " & First(Fields!ISO2Chars.Value, "InvoiceHeader") & First(Fields!TaxNumber.Value, "InvoiceHeader"))
```

I don't see how my syntax is any different to `IIF(Fields!ExitReason.Value = 7, 1, 0)`

Comment: You need to add a second part for the IIF condition turns out to be FALSE. Add a comma prior to the double close brackets and enter something that needs to be returned when the value is not null

Comment: Can't I do IFF NULL show IS02Chars else Show IS02Chars AND TaxNumber? The second part acts as my not null

Comment: Are these numeric value? If so. you'll need to cast these as strings (`Cstr` ) if you want to concatenate with other values...

Comment: @Greg2 I'm sure `=IFF` is not correct syntax, it should normally be `=IIF`. Plus you would want to do as Miguel said and cast if your values are numeric before concatenating them.

Comment: @Greg2 I completely missed the `=IFF`! Good spotting! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
  =IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!TaxNumber.Value, "InvoiceHeader")), ": "
 & First(Fields!ISO2Chars.Value, "InvoiceHeader") , ": " &
 First(Fields!ISO2Chars.Value, "InvoiceHeader") &
 First(Fields!TaxNumber.Value, "InvoiceHeader" ) )
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.